# Smooth extension of conformal maps mapping onto Jordan domains

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

Let $\gamma:[0,2\pi] \to \mathbb C$ be a $C^{1,\alpha}$ Jordan curve. ($0<\alpha<1$)

More precisely, $\gamma'$ is nonvanishing and is of class $C^{\alpha}$ (as a periodic function on $\mathbb R$).

By the Riemann mapping theorem, there exists a conformal map $f$ onto the interior component of $\gamma$, defined on the open unit disk.

I want to see a proof of the following theorem. (or, at least a reference)

> $f$ can be extended to a (non-analytic) homeomorphism of the complex plane onto itself, with
> non-vanishing Hölder-continuous gradient.

For anyone's interest, this is an exercise from the book "Pommerenke - boundary behaviour of conformal maps", page 50.

Comment: Surely you meant $\gamma'\in C^\alpha$, not $C^{1,\alpha}$? Your version says $\gamma\in C^{1,\alpha}$ if and only if $\gamma'\in C^{1,\alpha}$; that can't be right...

Comment: Thanks for your correction, Ullrich.

Comment: I don't have the actual reference, but in case it helps, there's a long paper by Krantz somewhere on this topic.